# Finding K Nearest Neighbor of a subset of samples efficiently in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have numpy array of points whose coordinates are in T.
I want to find the 3 nearest neighbors of a subset of points T1 such that these neighbors are in {T-T1}. I know the indices of rows representing the points in T1.
How can this be done efficiently in python3?

Comment: Really easy with numpy. What did you try?

Comment: nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors = 4, algorithm = 'ball_tree').fit(T2).   


distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(T1)

where T2 = T-T1

but the problem is if I separate the two subsets, then I lose the indices of the point concerned and its neighbors in the original numpy array T. Is there a way to get their indices as per the array T?